# querySelectorAll gives me an array contains just one element

Tags: javascript

I append some div elements with  class="todo" to the parent div with id ="no_status". when I console.log the div parent it shows me the div with all element childs have class="todo" but when i console log all divs with class="todo" using queryselectorall it shows just an array with one element that was in html before i append more class="todo" divs. thank you for your answer.
code pen link: https://codepen.io/mahdi74/pen/qBYLvZr

javascript:

```js
function addTodo(){
   
   if(todoInput.value.trim()){
      
      let closeBtn = document.createElement("span")
      closeBtn.className = "close"
      closeBtn.innerHTML = "&times;"
      
      let newTodo = document.createElement("div")
      newTodo.className = "todo"
      newTodo.draggable = "true"
      newTodo.append(todoInput.value.trim(), closeBtn)

      noStatusColumn.append(newTodo)
      todoInput.value = ""
      modal.style.top = "-50%"

      console.log(todoElems)           // it gives me an array with just one element
      console.log(noStatusColumn)     //but when i console log 
   }                                   
}
```

Comment: Post your [mcve] in your question please

Comment: You need to reassign `todoElems` after you add a new todo. It's not a live nodelist, it doesn't update automatically. If you use `document.getElementsByClassName` it will update by itself.

Comment: If you make a change in the DOM ( like append a new element with the todo class) you have to call `document.querySelectorAll` again to see the changes. In your code it seems that you call it only once at the initialization of `todoElems`

Comment: thank you. I will minimize it for my next question surely. I didnt know about the rules. but why the parent update itself and it shows the todo class elements every time that I console log it.. I called it using queryselector.

Answer (score 0):

You're only setting `todoElems` the first time the page load. It won't automatically update

You need to do `todoElems = document.querySelectorAll(".todo")` inside the `addTodo` function to give it all the elements